# Redirect from one domain to another with path

Tags: .htaccess

I'm attempting to redirect this domain, having changed the primary domain of the website.

I've managed to get it to redirect all incoming traffic to the homepage, but I'd like to send the full url to the new primary domain intact, and the solution is eluding me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staffhunt\.org\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.staffhunt\.org\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*|/?)$ "https\:\/\/www\.fleet\-oil\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I thought the last line should be as follows, but it doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^(.*|/?)$ "https\:\/\/www\.fleet\-oil\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Apache on CentOS 7, if it helps

Comment: Yes, that last line should work OK. (Although the regex can be simplified to just `(.*)`.) Do you have any other directives? Maybe you have a conflict? Btw, all the backslash-escapes in the _substitution_ string are unnecessary (although not a _problem_).

Comment: @MrWhite removing the backslashes seems to have solved the problem, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: That's great, glad you resolved the problem. However, just removing the backslashes would not have resolved this - there must have been something else. (?)